# Open default email client and pre-populate content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to automatically open a user's default email client when they click sendMail button a page. 
I need to populate the email subject, to address, body and attach pdf document.

How can I achieve this in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This may help for you:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=look at this website&body=Hi,I found this website
and thought you might like it http://www.geocities.com/wowhtml/">tell a friend</a>
```